# How to focus on an input text with a value using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a todo list similar to Google Keep where when I am focusing on a particular row and when pressing:

1. enter, it will create a new list item and trasfer focus to that list item
2. backspace, it will delete current list item and focus on the previous item assuming there is one.

HTML

```
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <h2>Plan</h2>
        <ul class="list-group list-group-sortable todo-list">

            @foreach (Models.ViewModels.PlanViewModel plan in Model.listPlan)
            {
            <li class="sortable list-group-item">
                <div class="d-inline">
                    <span class="text"><input id="@plan.Id" sort="@plan.Sort" class="plans" type="text" value="@plan.Description" /></span>
                    <span class="tools">
                        <i class="editPlan fa fa-thumb-tack"></i>
                        <i class="deletePlan fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </li>
            }
            <li class="list-group-item non-sortable disabled" style="height:55px;">
                <div style="float: right;">
                    <button id="savePlan" class="btn btn-info btn-group-sm">Save</button>
                    <button id="clearPlan" class="btn btn-default  btn-group-sm">Clear</button>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Javascript

```
        $(document).on("keydown", "input.plans", function (event) {
            var KeyID = event.keyCode;

            //on keypress enter 
            if (KeyID == 13) {
                $('<li class="sortable list-group-item"><div class="d-inline"><span class="text"><input class="plans" type="text" /></span><span class="tools"><i class="editPlan fa fa-thumb-tack"></i><i class="deletePlan fa fa-trash-o"></i></span></div></li>').insertAfter($(this).parent().parent().parent()[0]);
                $(this).parent().parent().parent().next().find('input').focus();
            }
            //on keypress backspace
            else if (KeyID == 8 && $(this).val().trim() === '') {
                var prevElement = $($(this).parent().parent().parent().prev().find('input')[0]);
                $(this).parent().parent().parent().remove();
                $(prevElement).focus(); //This doesn't focus on previous List Item
            }
        });
```

I have managed to make the enter part work but the backspace doesn't work properly.

**What it's supposed to do**

When current list item is empty it deletes the list item and focuses on the previous list item.

**What it actually does**

When current list item is empty it deletes the list item and deletes the last letter of the value of the previous list item when

```
$(prevElement).focus();
```

is invoked (which I find weird).

Comment: var prevElement = $(this).parent().parent().parent().prev().find('input')[0];

Comment: Isn't `var prevElement = $($(this).parent().parent().parent().prev().find('input')[0]);` supposed to be `var prevElement = $(this).parent().parent().parent().prev().find('input')[0]);` ?

Comment: it is.syntax err

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `event.preventDefault();` after `$(prevElement).focus();`.
This will prevent the last letter of the previous item to be deleted.

[jQuery preventDefault documentation](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

Comment: I will be trying this one. Let you know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Your backspace action is still there, you need to "cancel" it with event.Handled = True

Comment: Now it makes sense why it delete the text on the previous Element.